# Any way to find whether the IPAddress falls in Private Range

Tags: java

I am working on code where I need to find whether the ipAddress belongs to Private Range or not. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

UPDATED-

This is my method-

```
    if(isPrivateIPAddress(ipAddress)) {

     //do whatever you want

}



private static boolean isPrivateIPAddress(InetAddress address, String range) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String ipAddress = address.getHostAddress();
    return ipAddress.startsWith( range );
}
```

So I am not sure what is the address we need to pass in the above if loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this method, you can determine if an IP address starts with the defined private range:

```
public static boolean isInPrivateRange(InetAddress address, String range)
{
    String ipAddress = address.getHostAddress();
    return ipAddress.startsWith( range );
}
```

Sample invocations:

```
isInPrivateRange( address, "192.168." );
isInPrivateRange( address, "172.16." );
isInPrivateRange( address, "127.0." );
```

Sample program:

```
try
{
    InetAddress ipAddress = InetAddress.getByName( "google.com" );
    String range = "192.168";           
    System.out.println(isInPrivateRange( ipAddress, range ));
}
catch ( UnknownHostException e )
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I just updated my question. Can you help me with that. Thanks

Comment: @RaihanJamal I have added a sample program.

Answer (score 1):

Inet4Address has methods to test if the address is private. isSiteLocalAddress() returns true if the address is one of 10/8, 172.16/12 and 192.168/16.

Answer (score 0):

Well, off the top of my head, in general, if the IP address starts with 10. ,  127.0 , 192.168. ,  or 172.16.  , then you might be able to assume its private.   There might be some caveats to this though, so dont take my answer as gospel.

```
24-bit block 10.0.0.0 – 10.255.255.255 16,777,216 single class A 10.0.0.0/8 (255.0.0.0) 24 bits 
20-bit block 172.16.0.0 – 172.31.255.255 1,048,576 16 contiguous class Bs 172.16.0.0/12 (255.240.0.0) 20 bits 
16-bit block 192.168.0.0 – 192.168.255.255 65,536 256 contiguous class Cs 192.168.0.0/16 (255.255.0.0) 16 bits
```

Also, http://networking.ringofsaturn.com/IP/subnets.php

I don't know how to do it, but you might be able to programmatically apply a standard subnet mask to the ip address, look at the result, and determine if the ip is private:
[image]

Comment: _Technically_ the IP addresses you've listed are reserved for private networks and the core routers of the internet will not route them.  That said, there's no guarantee that some bozo network admin wouldn't try to use an internal IP addressing scheme that doesn't fall in one of those ranges...